# How to click a dynamic element

Tags: java, xpath, anchor

I'm trying to figure out the xpath which retrieve the "Projects (x)" from the following html, but without any results:

```
<li class="">
    <span id="c1025_ctl">
        <a id="c1025">
            <span>Similar people</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</li>
<li class="tabs-selected">
    <span id="c1016_ctl">
        <a id="c1016">
            <span>Projects (x)</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</li>
<li class="">
    <span id="c1037_ctl">
        <a id="c1037">
            <span>Info</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</li>
```

I've tried so far with `//a[contains(.,'Projects (x)')]/span` and `//a[contains(.,'Projects (x)')]`

Comment: What element are you trying to get? The A or the DIV element?

Comment: hi StefanE , I'm trying to get the a element

Comment: you can try //a[contains(text(),'Projects (x)')]

Comment: I think there's also some confusion about whether you want to retrieve an element or the text.

Comment: <li class="">
<span id="c1025_ctl">
<a id="c1025">
<span>Similar people</span>
</a>
</span>
</li>
<li class="tabs-selected">
<span id="c1016_ctl">
<a id="c1016">
<span>Projects (x)</span>
</a>
</span>
</li>
<li class="">
<span id="c1037_ctl">
<a id="c1037">
<span>Info</span>
</a>
</span>
</li>

Comment: @Mary. That should go into your question. It's very difficult to read as a comment. Please update by clicking the 'edit' button under the question.

Comment: I have added more ex. Also I've tried with //a[contains(text(), 'Projects (x)')]  but no result :( .

Comment: Here is my code    public void clickMenuItem(String item)
    {

        WebElement menu = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//nav//span[text()" + "=\"" + item + "\"] | //a[contains(.,\"" + item + "\")]"));

        if (menu != null) {
            menu.click();
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

If `id`s are known when crafting your `XPath` and are consistent, the following should be preferred :

```
//a[@id="c1016"]
```

If you can only make your search based on the text, you could use this :

```
//a[./span/text()="Projects (x)"]
```

I tested these on http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath where I successfully retrieved the target `a` tag after using your example data encapsulated in a root tag (in order to make it valid XML) ; I can't however share the results as the site's `save` function seems to remove everything from the XPath field after the first quote.

Concerning the `Java` code you added in a comment, I would try to invoke the `By.xpath(...).toString()` method hoping it would display the whole constructed XPath. This might point out errors in its construction. Note that I don't know Selenium and can only hope the `By.toString` method will behave this way.

If it doesn't, I'd use my IDE debugger to inspect the `By` item created by the invocation of `By.xpath(...)` and check out its fields, expecting to find one containing the whole constructed XPath.

Comment: I use this plugin in chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en then you can test your xpath on the page directly

Answer (score 0):

You could try the xpath :

`//span[. = 'Projects (x)'][parent::a]/parent::a` if you want to get the element `a`,

Remove `parent::a` at the end if you want just `span`